# Почему не происходит измение глобального или даже не глобального элемента в response ajax?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет! Столкнулся с такой проблемой - не обновлятся элемент в респонсе. Суть такая: после всех проверок происходит ajax запрос. Туда я посылаю один параметр - число записей, которые надо вернуть. В ответ мне приходят сами записи вместе с числом, которое должно уже использоваться в следущем ajax запросе. Типа отправляю число 15, в ответ приходит уже число 30, затем следующий запрос - отправляю 30, приходит 45, и т.д.. Думаю это понятно. Но по сути должно работать, но нифига. Число не изменяется в респонсе.

Сам скрипт:

```
    function onEntry(entry) {
      entry.forEach((change) => {
        if(change.target.dataset.id == elements[elements.length - 1].dataset.id){
            if(entry[entry.length - 1].isIntersecting){
                window.count = document.getElementById('article-count').dataset.count;
                console.log(window.count)
                axios.post('api/load',{
                    count: window.count,
                }).then((response) =>{
                    window.count = response.data.count;
                    console.log(window.count)
                    //какой-то код
                });
            }
        }
      });
    }

    let options = {
      threshold: 0.1,
      root: null,
      rootMargin: '0px'
    };

    let observer = new IntersectionObserver(onEntry, options);
    let elements = document.querySelectorAll('article.lazy-load');
    for (let elm of elements) {
      observer.observe(elm);
    }
```

А вот сам результат из консоли: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В `document.getElementById('article-count').dataset.count` по дефолту стоит число 15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы посылаете на сервер в цикле все время одно и то же число из `...dataset.count`.

Вынесите строку

```
window.count = document.getElementById('article-count').dataset.count;
```

из цикла.

Comment: Хм... да, правильно. Работает. Спасибо

Comment: @Евгений Пожалуйста. Успехов!

Comment: Благодарю. И тебе того же)